# Casting COM types in C++

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have the following COM types: `Project`, `ContainerItem` and `Node`.
`Project` has a collection property with an `Append` function that accepts `ContainerItem`s.

In C#, using type libraries I can send a `Node` object to the `Append` function and the library works as expected:

```
var prj = new Project();
var node = new Node();
prj.collection.Append(node);
```

In C++ I tried a direct pointer cast expecting this is what C# was doing, but it ends up in an error:

```
ProjectPtr prj;
prj.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Project));
NodePtr node;
node.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Node));
prj->collection->Append((ContainerItem**)&node.GetInterfacePtr());
```

Is there a specific way to these type of COM pointer casts in C++? What am I missing?

Comment: C-style casts are not valid on COM interfaces, you must use QueryInterface().  C# does it automatically but you have to do it yourself in C++.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that `Append` takes `ContainerItem**` as a parameter. That would make no sense. What's the declaration of `Append`? What's the relationship, if any, between `Node` and `ContainerItem`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The definition is Container::Append(ContainerItem**, long*), the second parameter can be null by the way. I don't know the relationship between Node and ContainerItem as it is not represented in the .tli file the compiler creates from the COM DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM casting is done with the [`QueryInterface()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78xw8kzk.aspx) method. The object is queried for its support of the interface (based on the GUID), and if the interface is supported, the internal reference counter is incremented (see `AddRef()`) and a pointer to the interface is returned. [MSDN has more detail on the inner workings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521.aspx).

C++ does not directly support the code generation for the "COM cast" as C# does, but its implementation is simple enough.

```
struct bad_com_cast : std::runtime_error {
    bad_com_cast() : std::runtime_error("COM interface not supported") {}
};

template <class To, class From>
To* qi_cast(From* iunknown)
{
    HRESULT hr  = S_OK;
    To* ptr = NULL;
    if (iunknown) {
        hr = iunknown->QueryInterface(__uuidof(To), (void**)(&ptr));
        if (hr != S_OK) {
            throw bad_com_cast(); // or return NULL
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Using the above "cast", the sample can be implemented as follows;

```
ContainerItem* ci = qi_cast<ContainerItem>(node);
prj->collection->Append(&ci);
```

If the ATL library is being used, you can use [`ATL::CComQIPtr<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc177dxw.aspx) directly to obtain the equivalent semantics;

```
auto ci = CComQIPtr<ContainerItem>(node);
if (ci) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @HansPassant commented, I had to use the QueryInterface function:

```
ContainerItem* ci = nullptr;
node.QueryInterface(__uuidof(ContainerItem), ci);
prj->collection->Append(&ci);
```